# Give in cyclic form an odd permutation $\pi$ so that...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Give in cyclic form an odd permutation $\pi$ so that $\pi ∈ S_9$ so that $\pi^2 \neq id$ and $\pi^{10} = id$

I have started like this:

$o(\pi) | 10$ which means that $o(\pi) = 1,2,5,10$. I don't know how to choose which of those to be the order. Any help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3):

$(1,2,3,4,5)(6,7)$. It is odd since it has exactly one cycle of even length and its order is $10$. Remember the order of a permutation is the least common multiple of its cycles lengths.

Comment: What about $8,9$in your cyclic permutation? Plus can't it be $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5,6,7,8,9)$

Comment: @DoubleOseven That permutation is not odd.

Comment: that one also works but is not odd, if an element doesn't appear in a cyclic form it is usually assumed that it is a fixed point, so the permutation I have in mind is $(1,2,3,4,5)(6,7)(8)(9)$

Comment: Is this $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5,6,7,8,9)$ even? (Just want to make sure)

Comment: yes, it is even. It has an even number of cycles of even length (zero, to be precise).